# Can`t manually delete record from sqlite table, because related table with __old does not exists

Tags: django, sqlite

I want to manually delete records from sqlite table(witch was created with Django 1.10, Table from i want to delete records called main.storage_claim, it has relation to main.storage_claimlist), but got error: Error deleting record: no such table: main.storage_claimlist__old.

I dont know why it want this table.

I have only main.storage_claimlist without __old.

Btw, i`m using DB Browser for SQLite as gui tool for working with sqlite.

Can someone explain what the heck is __old?

ClaimList model:

```py
class ClaimList(models.Model):
    """ Claim list contains one to many claim. Used for grouping claims. """
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, null=True)
    from_storage = models.ForeignKey(
        Storage, related_name='from_storage', blank=True, null=True, default=True)
    to_storage = models.ForeignKey(
        Storage, related_name='to_storage', blank=True, null=True, default=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    separation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    insurance_company = models.ForeignKey(
        InsuranceCompany, null=True, blank=True)
    patient = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=False)
```

Claim model:

```py
class Claim(models.Model):
    """ Claim contain information about what need to be transefer """
    medicine = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    claim_list = models.ForeignKey(ClaimList, blank=True, null=True)
    requested_amount = models.DecimalField(
        default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
    given_amount = models.DecimalField(
        default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
    requested_unit = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    given_unit = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    from_income = models.ForeignKey(Income, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    is_will_be_accepted_in_future = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=5)
    sum = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=5)

    objects = ClaimManager()
```

Comment: Add the `models` to the question along with error trace.

Comment: i will add model code, but not error trace, becouse i dont want to delete records with django orm, i want delete it manually(using some gui tool or raw sql query). Database was created by Django.

Comment: Perhaps there is a delete trigger on storage_claimlist table?